# How is if statement executed in NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia, cpu-architecture

As much as know GPU cores are very simple and can only execute  basic  mathematic instructions.
If I have a kernel with an if statement, then what does execute that if statement? Fp32, Fp64 and Int32 can only execute operations with floats, doubles and integers, not a COMPARE instruction, am I wrong. What happens if I have printf function in kernel? Who executes that.

[image]

Comment: [GPU Flow-Control Idioms](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-iv-general-purpose-computation-gpus-primer/chapter-34-gpu-flow-control-idioms)

Comment: "*As much as know GPU cores are very simple and can only execute basic mathematic instructions.*" That hasn't been true since the mid-2000s, if not earlier. It certainly isn't true for a "tensor core".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, this is how calculations are done, what about the comparasion itself, who does that?

Comment: To me the question isn't quite clear: The comparison (i.e. `a > b`) and the conditional (i.e. `if (c) f(); else g();`) are separate instructions.

Comment: A lot of units are not shown in this simplistic diagram. If you look at the pipelines (not units) section of https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/ProfilingGuide/#metrics-decoder you can see the cbu unit (convergence barrier unit) is responsible for branches. You can read about predicated execution on Cuda here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#predicated-execution

Answer (score 3):

Compare instructions *are* arithmetic instructions, you can implement a comparison with subtraction and a flag register, and GPGPUs have them.
But they are often not advertised as much as the number-crunching capability of the whole GPU.

NVIDIA doesn't publish the machine code documentation for their GPUs nor the ISA of the respective assembly (called SASS).
Instead, NVIDIA maintains the PTX language which is designed to be more portable across different generations while still being very close to the actual machine code.

[PTX is a predicated architecture](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#predicated-execution). The `setp` instruction (which again, is just a subtraction with a few caveats) sets the value of the defined predicate registers and these are used to conditionally execute other instructions. Including the `bra` instruction which is a branch, making it possible to execute conditional branches.

One could argue that PTX is not SASS but it seems the predicate architecture is what NVIDIA GPUs, at least, [used to do](https://github.com/laanwj/decuda).

[AMD GPUs seem to use the traditional approach to branching](https://github.com/olvaffe/gpu-docs/blob/master/amd-open-gpu-docs/AMD_GCN3_Instruction_Set_Architecture.pdf): there are comparison instructions (e.g. `S_CMP_EQ_U64`) and conditional branches (e.g. `S_CBRANCH_SCCZ`).

[Intel GPUs also rely on predication](https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/blob/master/documentation/visa/3_execution_model.md) but have different instructions for divergent vs non-divergent branches.

So GPGPUs do have branch instructions, in fact, their SIMT model has to deal with the [branch divergence problem](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Emoreno/CS433-CS9624/Resources/Reducing_branch_divergence_in_GPU_programs.pdf).

Before c. 2006 GPUs were not fully programmable and programmers had to rely on other tricks (like data masking or branchless code) to implement their kernel.
Keep in mind that at the time it was not widely accepted that one could execute arbitrary programs or make arbitrary shading effects with GPUs.    GPUs relaxed their programming constraints with time.

---

Putting a `printf` in a CUDA kernel won't probably work because there is no C runtime on the GPU (remember the GPU is an entirely different executor from the CPU) and the linking would fail I guess.
You can theoretically force a GPU implementation of the CRT and design a mechanism to call syscalls from the GPU code but that would be unimaginably slow since GPUs are not designed for this kind of work.
**EDIT**: Apparently NVIDIA actually did implement a `printf` on the GPU that prints to a buffer shared with host.
The problem here is not the presence of branches but the very nature of `printf`.

Comment: I'm now imagining (with my limited knowledge of GPUs) implementing `printf` as a shader.  Each pixel in the region where the text output should go independently runs the whole printf code to format a string, and then figures out which character of the string the current pixel comes from (lets assume a monospaced font so there's no serial dependency).  Then produce a colour from a font glyph for that character as the result for this pixel shader.  So a `%f` format has to run `dtoa` thousands of times, once for each pixel in the area. :P

Comment: @Peter Cordes Device-side `printf()` in CUDA simply stuffs relevant information into a buffer. The actual printing occurs on the host side, emptying the buffer. The `printf()` buffer size is configurable by programmers.

Comment: @njuffa: Oh, didn't realize device-side `printf` that was a real thing!  Thanks.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom While NVIDIA does not provide full documentation of the architecture-specific machine code (SASS) instructions, lists giving an overview of the available instructions are provided in the documentation for the [CUDA Binary Utilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html), chapter 4. By dumping SASS for a kernel with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`, one can easily verify that conditional branches are implemented as predicated `BRA` instructions at the SASS level, as noted in the answer (unless the compiler eliminated such a branch through branch conversion).

Comment: opencl defines `printf`, the output is queued to the host and executed there. See https://man.opencl.org/printfFunction.html